# Getting import error while using pyfcm

Tags: django, python-3.x, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

installed pyfcm using : `pip install pyfcm`

```
 from pyfcm import FCMNotification
ImportError: cannot import name 'FCMNotification'
```

getting this import error in both python2.7 and python3.5

Answer (score 1):

To install this package with `conda` run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyfim
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 pyfim
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyfim
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pyfim
```

Answer (score 0):

After many tries i resolved this error by just restarting my system.

and here is my working code which triggers notification when a value change in fire-base database .

```
from pyfcm import FCMNotification
import pyrebase

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="type server key here")
registration_id = "get this token from your app"
message_title = "Fire Alert"
message_body = "Fire Breakage dehradun"

config = {
"apiKey": "",
"authDomain": "",
"databaseURL": "",
"projectId": "",
"storageBucket": "",
"messagingSenderId": ""
};

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
def stream_handler(post):
    print(post)
    if (post['data'] is 1):
        result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
        print (result)
my_stream = db.child("fire_sensor_status").stream(stream_handler, None)
```

hope this will help you out :)